# How can I fire an event in an option tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, html-select

I looked for a solution for this, but couldn't find it.

I have a simple select like this:

```
<select id="sltFiltroPedidos">
  <option value="todos">Todos</option>
  <option value="hoje">de hoje</option>
  <option value="semana">da semana</option>
  <option value="periodo">Período</option>
  <option value="pedido">Número do pedido</option>
</select>
```

Always the user clicks on an option, a javascript event must be fired.
The onChange event in the select doesn't work for me, because the user can choose the same option, and the event must be fired as well.

I tried the onClick event on options. It works on IE and FF, but doesn't work on Chrome.
Any ideas how can I do it?

Comment: What doesn't work in Chrome? http://jsfiddle.net/t9suH/

Comment: Shouldn't the state be the same if they pick the same item? Seems like you should have a "Pick One" option.

Comment: The onClick event in the option doesn't work on Chrome. I open a fancybox in the onClick, and that one must be opened every time the user clicks on the correspondent option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote a code but it is not working on IE, just give it a try:  http://jsfiddle.net/shahe_masoyan/scuhb/1/

```
<select id="sltFiltroPedidos">
  <option value="todos">Todos</option>
  <option value="hoje">de hoje</option>
  <option value="semana">da semana</option>
  <option value="periodo">Período</option>
  <option value="pedido">Número do pedido</option>
</select>


var isOpen = false;
$('#sltFiltroPedidos').on('mouseup', function () {
    if (isOpen){
        alert(this.value);
    }
    isOpen = !isOpen;
});
```

Comment: I just changed the mouseup to the click event, and that works in both browsers. Thanks a lot for the idea, man!

Comment: I didn't vote up just because I don't have reputation for that.. =D

Comment: Before I forget, I also included a $('#sltFiltroPedidos').blur(function () { isOpen = false; }), in case the user clicks on the select and leaves it, without choose an option.

Answer (score 2):

As per your question you can do following :-

```
<select id="sel" onblur="showme()">
  <option value="todos" >Todos</option>
  <option value="hoje" >de hoje</option>
  <option value="semana" >da semana</option>
  <option value="periodo" >Período</option>
  <option value="pedido" >Número do pedido</option>
</select>
```

But i don't know this right option or not. But this will work as you told.

```
function showme()
{
    alert(document.getElementById('sel').value);
}
```

Comment: That was my first code. But that didn't work on Chrome for me, and I don't know why.

Comment: I have edited this if it is useful for you then try it

Comment: ok, this is an old thread.. this works, but somehow it takes a lot of time to execute... you know why?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `onclick` like,

```
var prevValue=$('select').val();
$('select').on('click',function(){
   if(prevValue==this.value) // code for same values
   // your code to run
});
```

Comment: But the onClick event will be fired when the user clicks on the select, and before he chooses the option, right? That's a problem for me, because the event must be fired only after the user selects his option.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  In my task, I needed to get the value of the selected option. This helped me:

```
let selectedOption = "";
<select>.addEventListener("change", event => {
    selectedOption = event.target.value
});
```

The select variable is, obviously, the tag .
It might look strange, but select takes the value of the chosen option, that's why the code works.

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
 $('#sltFiltroPedidos').on('change', function() {
    alert( this.value );// or this.val()
 });
```

Hope this will work for you

Comment: As I said, that doesn't work for me, because the event won't be fired when the user selects the same option.